# Perforce file(s) not in client view

Tags: perforce

I have setup a new Perforce server via docker. I have an admin user and I can connect to it successfully.

It is of course an empty server, so I created a new workspace called `foo` with the following view:

```
//depot/... //foo/depot/...
```

Adding any new file fails in:

```
/Users/test/workspace_foo/file - file(s) not in client view.
```

I found this problem hundreds of times, but I am beyond the step of missing to create a workspace view, still it does not work. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your workspace's root is `/Users/test/workspace_foo`.  That's what `//foo` in your client view corresponds to:

```
Client: foo
Root: /Users/test/workspace_foo
View:
    //depot/... //foo/depot/...
```

right?  So that means that:

```
//depot/... <-> /Users/test/workspace_foo/depot/...
```

*Sidebar: The `p4 where` command will show you the depot-syntax, client-syntax, and local-syntax version of any given path; use `p4 where //...` to see your entire client mapping with overlapping view entries disambiguated and client paths expanded to local syntax.*

The local file you're trying to add is not within the local path of the client view you've defined, which is why you're getting the error `file(s) not in client view`.  If you want to leave your view mapping the way it is, you'll need to move `file` into a path under `/Users/test/workspace_foo/depot` in order to be able to `add` it.  Whatever path you create on the client relative to `/Users/test/workspace_foo/depot` will be created on the server relative to `//depot`.

If you want `/Users/test/workspace_foo/file` to map to `//depot/file`, then change your View like this:

```
Client: foo
Root: /Users/test/workspace_foo
View:
    //depot/... //foo/...
```

which means that:

```
//depot/... <-> /Users/test/workspace_foo/...
```

and therefore:

```
/Users/test/workspace_foo/file <-> //depot/file
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled hard on this. And I'm not sure if I finally understood the real cause why it's working now.

To me, it looks like you need to create the mapping with the three dots as expression in order to be able to create a more specific one.

[Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/793pj.png)

However, after I added the 'three-dot-mapping' I could finally add all my files without any trouble. What doubts me a little is that after I opened the Mapping again, my 'three-dot-mapping' disappeared, and it just showed me a mapping to the folder I added.

As I understood, you need the

> //depot/... <-> /Users/test/workspace_foo/...

mapping in order to be able to create a

> //depot/anotherFolder <-> /Users/test/workspace_foo/anotherFolder

mapping. Also make sure, that first you add a file / folder directly under `/Users/test/workspace_foo/...`.

If anyone has further explanations for this, I look forward hearing them.