Perforce won’t let me add files to depot because “file(s) not in client view.” for my unreal engine project
So here’s my situation. I have a desktop perforce server that I already have a project on for a group game project for one of my classes. The server keeps all of those files in a depot called “depot” because I was new to perforce and I just named it that. After a bit the project grew and I have a full game project stored in there. Since I’m not working on that game project anymore, I’ve started a new project and I wanted to use my already setup perforce desktop server. I’m using Perforce Helix P4V to access the server, its the GUI if that matters.
So I followed this guide:
https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/tutorials/BEqk/unreal-engine-adding-additional-projects-to-perforce-using-p4v-as-simply-as-possible
I found it really helpful until I got to the part where you add your workspace files. I created a new depot called ProjectMomentos and created a new workspace with a new folder and copy and pasted the unreal engine project into that workspace folder. The files show up in perforce but their only showing up because I filtered it to “show files not in depot”. Theirs something I’m doing wrong but I can’t figure it out. Whenever I try to add those workspace files, a bunch of warning messages pop up and say this unreal engine asset “file(s) not in client view.” I’ve been trying to fix this for hours but nothing seems to work. It will say “no files opened” “311 warnings reported” before showing all the warnings. If anyone can help, I would seriously appreciate it.
So I tired switching and mapping different depots. Didn't work. Created and deleted 10+ workspaces to keep testing but nothing worked. Extremely stuck
Update:
Tried the "p4 client -o" command and here is what I got back
Client: ProjectMomentosWorkspace

Update: 2024/08/26

Access: 2024/08/26

Owner:  {my name}

Host:   DESKTOP-19Q8KE8

Description:
        Created by {my name}.

Root:   F:\UnrealEngineProjects\ProjectMomentos

Options:        noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir noaltsync

SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged

LineEnd:        local

View:
        //ProjectMomentos/... //ProjectMomentosWorkspace/ProjectMomentos/...
        -//depot/... //ProjectMomentosWorkspace/depot/...
        -//depot/* //ProjectMomentosWorkspace/depot/*
        //ProjectMomentos/* //ProjectMomentosWorkspace/ProjectMomentos/*

I feel like I've tried everything and nothing works. I tried what the other posts said and I still get "file(s) not in client view"

I GOT IT WORKING. I'll try to explain what I did to the best of my ability. Used chatGPT for a bit I redid the view mapping command for the workspace.
For some reason:
//ProjectMomentos/... //Test5/ProjectMomentos/...
//ProjectMomentos/ProjectMausoleum/... //Test5/ProjectMausoleum/...

this is what worked. I'm not exactly sure why this worked. But it worked

You'll need to include your client spec.  Open a terminal window from P4V, run p4 client -o, and copy and paste that into your question (the text, not a screenshot), along with an example of the local path of the file(s) you're trying to add.  The problem is simply that the two things don't match, and that's a really easy problem to fix, but it's hard to tell you exactly how exactly to make two things match when we can't see either one.

This general type of question is probably the most common thing that new Perforce users run into and you'll find a lot of examples on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536642/3799759

Again, to explain how to fix the client view or why your fix worked we'd need to see the path of the local files you're trying to add in addition to the client definition.  The client view is what translates your local file paths into depot file paths; if a file can't be translated, you get "not in client view", simple as that.  Glad you got it working!

Looking carefully at the differences between the different versions of your client view, the difference seems to be that the path F:\UnrealEngineProjects\ProjectMomentos\ProjectMausoleum has no mapping in the original client view, because the view only maps the local directory F:\UnrealEngineProjects\ProjectMomentos\ProjectMomentos (ProjectMomentos is repeated -- once in the Root, once in the View).  The view you probably wanted is simply //ProjectMomentos/... //ProjectMomentosWorkspace/....
